# is there any time to install apps same time in ubuntu?

Tags: apt, 18.04, system-installation, package-management

I know maybe it sounds a bad idea to install apps with the terminal same time. 
as you know when I install some apps and during installation, if I open up another terminal and installing another package it gave us lock error ... is there any way to bypass this error and install apps same time?
thank you.

Comment: No, there is no way to do it.

Comment: You can run `sudo apt install app1 app2 app3` to install `app1`, `app2`, and `app3` *one after another* to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No! Don't do that!!

The installation process is locked when it is running for a reason. The system won't allow if you try to install two incompatible apps at the same time.

Unlike Windows, Linux apps depend on lots of common files. If one of those is incompatible with the rest of the system, your system may not boot.

You can always install multiple apps in a single command:

```
sudo apt install app1 app2 app53
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It will now "screw up" the system, it won't allow to do it. Everything else is correct.

Comment: Well... that is not a good idea, but Op didn't try to do it.

Comment: @Pilot6 OP asks "Is there any way to bypass this error...?" I have now deleted the comment with one way to do it. I agree it is a very bad idea.